# Mongodb doesn't get configured to PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I know this question has been asked plenty of times but I still can't solve the issue. I have tried almost every solution out there. I have added php_mongo.dll in "ext" directory. Then I added extension at the end of php.ini. I tried downloading mongo directly to my wamp directory as well. php_mongo is checked in PHP extensions. But still it gives the error when I try to run a simple program like this one

```
<?php
echo "hello";
$connection = new MongoClient(); // connects to localhost:27017


?>
```

It does print hello but then gives the error that MongoClient is unknown. 
My PHP is version 5.5.12 x64 and mongodb is also x64.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following using the wmapmanager menus

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> and click on the 2.X.X version number
```

This will cause wampmanager to rebuild all the SYMLINKS in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.X.X\bin` folder.

Are you sure you are editing the correct `php.ini` file. Use the wampmanager menu system to edit the correct `php.ini` file

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

You should add

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

Reboot the server

PS:
Check that you aren't using a wrong mongo php_driver.

Comment: Now I have got a new problem when I try to click it : php5.dll missing